# Escaping Correctly VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I understand this question has been asked before but I found the answers difficult to incorporate and because of that I'm asking for my own specific problem:

`Cells(counter, col).Value = "=MONTH(G2) & " - " & YEAR(G2)"`

I tried:

`Cells(counter, col).Value = "=MONTH(G2) & """ - """ & YEAR(G2)"`

But that failed. I'm a little confused how to escape properly and after reviewing the stackoverflow responses to this question I was still confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to achieve this:

> ```
> =MONTH(G2) & " - " & YEAR(G2)
> ```

So the string value for it needs to double-up the double quotes, like this:

```
=MONTH(G2) & "" - "" & YEAR(G2)
```

Therefore:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, col).Value = "=MONTH(G2) & "" - "" & YEAR(G2)"
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks. Ill select as answered once available.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the number-pair rather than a true date or a formula.  Here is a way to use worksheet functions within a *VBA* sub:

```
Sub Joseph()
    counter = 2
    col = 2
    Cells(counter, col).Value = "'" & [MONTH(G2)] & " - " & [YEAR(G2)]
End Sub
```

[image]

The single quote prevents Excel from converting the number-pair into a Date.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is:

```
Cells(counter, col).Formula = "=MONTH(G2) & "" - "" & YEAR(G2)"
```

One way to get formulas with internal double quotes correct is to start by substituting a placeholder for the internal double quotes:

```
Cells(counter, col).Formula = "=MONTH(G2) & DBLQUOTE - DBLQUOTE & YEAR(G2)"
```

where the right hand side is a simple literal string. Then replace every occurrence of `DBLQUOTE` with `""`, the escaped version of a double quote.

Note that I changed .Value to .Formula --- I think that's better.

Hope that helps.